# SELECT custom setting FROM pg_settings

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name='search_path'  
#> ["$user", public]  

SET application.currentuser = '123'  

SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name='application.currentuser'  
#> []
```

How is it possible to SELECT a custom setting?

Function current_setting() is not an option, since it will throw an error, if the custom setting is not set.

Comment: You could create a wrapper function uses `current_setting()` and traps the error. (Postgres 9.6 will have that built-in: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-admin.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
alter database mydbname set application.currentuser = '123';
```

At the next login variable will be available immediately using `show` command or `current_setting()` function.

```
alter database mydbname reset application.currentuser;
```

to remove it.